# Use the backend just to send all the data and filter the data with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm changing my application. At the moment, the production is running with NODE + EJS, and I want change to NODE.JS + ANGULAR. I started to change everything and I'm stuck on something.

In my new application, I want most of logic in my angular controllers, and I was using this piece of code to aggregate and return somethings:

```
  Booking.aggregate(
    [{
      '$group': {
        '_id': '$booking.date',
        'name': {
          '$first': '$booking.name'
        },
        'participants': {
          '$sum': '$booking.participants'
        },
        'attended': {
          '$sum': {
            '$cond': [{
              '$eq': ['$isActive', true]
            }, 1, 0]
          }
        },
        'bookings': {
          '$sum': 1
        }
      }
    }, {
      $sort: {
        'booking.date': -1
      }
    }],
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        res.send(result)
      }
    }
  );
```

Now, I want send all the data in JSON (obvious) to my angular controllers and then filter there.

My question is:

- Is this possible?
- Is there is anything to help me achieve this, maybe a ready for use plugin?
- And, which one is faster?

Comment: sending json from node is well documented

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do to recieve and handle JSON data from your back end, in angular, is use the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service. It is well documented, you can make GET requests to your back end and after the .success() set `$scope`.returnedJson to the returned data. Then access the returned json properties with $scope.returnedJson.propertyName. It's fairly simple, and $http is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I would not underestimate the power of mongodb's aggregation capabilities.

What you can do with that one aggregation call could potentially be a substantial amount of code trying to sort and filter the data.  If you have any semi-complex filtering/sorting, especially if it is a fairly substantial amount of data, I would just let mongodb handle it.

Additionally, your aggregation call can be modified easily, whereas if you need to change a custom built javaScript filter it could become a hassle.